# How to write a generalized web driver wait in Selenium

Tags: selenium

I am trying to write a generalized web driver wait to wait for elements to be clickable. But I found out online of Web Driver waits that are written specific to By.id or By.name.

Suppose Below are two WebElements

```
public WebElement accountNew() {
    WebElement accountNew = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@title='New']"));
    waitForElementtobeClickable(accountNew);
    return accountNew;
}

public WebElement accountName() {
    WebElement accountName = driver.findElement(By.id("acc2"));
    waitForElementtobeClickable(accountName);
    return accountName;
}
```

Below is the generalized waitofrelementtobeclickable.

```
public static void waitForElementtobeClickable(WebElement element) {        
        try {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
            System.out.println("Got the element to be clickable within 10 seconds" + element);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
            wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
            System.out.println("Got the element to be clickable within 20 seconds" + element);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions on how only one generalized code can be written for either xpath, or id, or class or Css can be written?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem to work" ? do you get errors?

Comment: No, there are no errors, but the call to the waitforelementclickable just gets bypassed and doesnt go through the actual waiting for 10 or 20 seconds process. Example: After I login to Salesforce application, I want the userName in the top panel to be clickable so that I can click on it and then click Logout.But the page is still loading after login, and the program just terminates saying element not found. But if I give an explicit sleep of 20 seconds, it works. So xpath/locator is not an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in your function, its in your `driver.findElement` as you try to locate the element before it exist in the DOM. You can use implicit wait

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

This will wait up for 10 seconds for any element to exist in the DOM before when locating it.

Or locate your element using explicit wait

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@title='New']")));
```

This will wait up to 10 seconds for your element to be visible.

You can (and should) use both of course.

You can change your code to something like that

```
public static WebElement waitForElementtobeClickable(By by) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(by));
    System.out.println("Got the element to be clickable within 10 seconds" + element);
    return element;
}

public WebElement accountNew() {
    WebElement accountNew = waitForElementtobeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@title='New']"));
    return accountNew;
}
```

You send your `By` locator to `waitForElementtobeClickable` and use `elementToBeClickable(By)` instead of `elementToBeClickable(WebElement)`, so you can use xpath, id, class etc.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Worked like a charm. I actually had an idea of it, but just could not get my head around to implement it. Also got confused since I am not using Page Factory model, and am using only one static driver, which is declared in the BasePage class.

Comment: @Ronnie Glad it worked. Feel free to accept this answer as the solution by clicking the green checkmark near it ;)